# Display problems on Angular Elements with Material Dialog (ShadowDom issue?)

Tags: angular, dialog, element, shadow-dom

I'm going to get in touch with Angular Elements on Angular 7 to build lightweight web components which can be simply deployed in existing web pages.
First tests were promising however I've got a display trouble with dialogs based on Angular Material (MatDialog). 
If I build the Angular component (FilterComponent) as Angular element and run the generated web component in a simple HTML5 web page the dialog box is displayed directly on the base web page instead of a detached box.

I use the currently stable version of Angular/cli 7.3.8.

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchElementComponent,
    FilterDialogComponent,
    FilterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [SearchElementComponent, FilterComponent, FilterDialogComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    // Convert `SearchElementComponent` to a custom element.
    const SearchElementElement = createCustomElement(SearchElementComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    // Register the custom element with the browser.
    customElements.define('search-element', SearchElementElement);

    const FilterComponentElement = createCustomElement(FilterComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('filter-element', FilterComponentElement);
  }
}
```

filter.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  template: `
    <button mat-mini-fab class="filer-button" (click)="openFilterDialog()" title="Filter">
      <i class="material-icons filter-icon">filter_list</i>
    </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class FilterComponent {
  topicMedical = true;
  topicPharma = true;
  topicBiotec = true;

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
  ) { }

  public openFilterDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FilterDialogComponent, {
      panelClass: 'filterDialog',
      autoFocus: false,
      minWidth: 350,
      maxWidth: '60%',
      maxHeight: '45%',
      data: {
        topicMedical: this.topicMedical,
        topicPharma: this.topicPharma,
        topicBiotec: this.topicBiotec,
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Filter dialog closed. ');
    });
  }
}
```

filter-dialog.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-dialog',
  templateUrl: './filter-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-dialog.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class FilterDialogComponent {


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FilterDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FilterDialogData) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Does anybody has a hint for me why does the dialog box not work as expected?

Displayed as expected as regular Angular app 
[image: Display as expected as regular Angular app]

However: Displayed as Angular Element / web component in a simple web page - not detached dialog box
[image: Display as Angular Element - not detached dialog box]

I will appreciate all your comments :-)

Comment: How are you building your app? Are you including zone.js inside your web elements? Maybe angular does not check changes properly? Try to use `ChangeDetectorRef` and manually trigger change detection after dialog was opened (`this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`)

Comment: @OleksiiMiroshnyk: Thanks for your response. Generally I build my web component with ngx-build-plus and load zone.js manually into the web page (index.html). As I understand your hint I tried to add `dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(_ => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges());` into the filter.components.ts file. However the display behavior didn't change. Did I understand your right? Or how should I implement your hint into the code?

Comment: Yes, you did, unless I suppose to do next: `this.dialog.open(); this.changeDetectirRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: If your dialog opens in you custom element properly than you need to check if all styles are included. Maybe you are not including cdk-overlay styles to you custom elements build.

Comment: Thanks again. Nevertheless, nothing changed after I put `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` directly after `this.dialog.open()`. I also tried to include the cdk-overlay styles into the filter.component.css files `@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';` without any changes of display behavior. Or how should I do this including of cdk-overlay styles into the custom elements?

Comment: @Mike42 have you resolve this problem?

Comment: @Piotr: Not yet, but I am going to try it with the current version of Angular again in the next weeks. Do you have any hint for me? Or do you face the same problem?

Comment: @Mike42 I wrote answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not a problem with modal and showing it. This is a problem with CSS files. I resolve this by adding css file inside into html. Try add this:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To do this in good way I rewrite CSS to component CSS and then everything will be ok. Also you can try to extract all your CSS from Material Dialog and other custom css to one file and then include it to your website. You should also read about ViewEncapsulation in Angular components.

Answer (score 0):

The Material dialog which is containing your "FilterComponent" is probably attached to the body element.

Thus making the dialog unreachable by the material styles you imported inside the Shadow DOM.

See related issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13837